# How to print the attributes of an java object in struts 2 using s:textfield tag

Tags: java, xml, struts

The object  `x` in `y`.java file has `x.a & x.b` I want those `x.a` and `x.b` to be displayed in a text field by writing code in jsp using struts 2 `<s:textfield>` tag. How to do this? Please help me.

I have tried several options like

```
value=%{x.a}
```

`value=%{#x.a}`.

Nothing worked and spent almost 5 hrs.

Should I do something like name="x" or value="x". My doubt is, how will the jsp page know that the x object is only accessed from the y.java file. How the mapping is done?

Answer (score 1):

"How the mapping is done?"

Your JSP can access objects exposed by YOUR ACTION, the Action that forwarded the JSP.

The mapping between which Action calls which JSP is done in the struts-config.xml file.

You can acces one object or property in an Action IF you have generated, or writed by hand, GETTERS methods for that property or object.

In your case, a getter for the X object in your Action, and GETTERS methods for the properties 'a' and 'b' in your object X.

If you are trying to access an object that is not in your Action, it should be static (with configuration allowing static methods access in struts-config.xml), or in Session, or in ValueStack, or something.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I create JSP struts2 templates, but if memory serves, it should be just

```
<s:textfield value="x.a" />
```

Have you tried that combination?

Comment: I am getting x.a again in the text field, but I want the value stored in that x.a, PLease help and thanks for your first reply.

Comment: Should I do something like name="x" or value="x". My doubt is, how will the jsp page know that the x object is only accessed from the y.java file. How the mapping is done?

Comment: Is the template being called?  If your object x has public getters in your class, and your JSP is being called via the dispatcher, then the template should have access to all public objects.  If it is just displaying `x`, then my first guess would be that you don't have a public `getX()` method in your class.  Can you post a copy of your class and/or your struts configuration (are you using XML or annotations)?

Comment: Where is the file contents?  Please provide corresponding struts config xml as well (and/or annotations).

Answer (score 0):

Step1...
    writing msg  in action class..
        example--
            request.setAttribute("message", "User deleted successfully");

Step2...
    gettng msg in jsp page..
        example--
                 <%= request.getAttribute("message") %>

setting attribute in request